# How to view .cblite2 files on Windows?

Tags: android, nosql, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I am developing an android application that uses Couchbase Lite, i have saved a mutubale document now i want to view the saved document by extracting the database file and viewing it in some viewer but there seems no option to view .cblite files on Windows.

**What i tried?**

**1-** Extracted .cblite file from device using Device File Explorer

[image]

**2-** First, i tried to view it in [DB Browser For SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), it allowed to select .sqlite3 file

On selecting .sqlite3 file, the view was like this
[image]

In above picture, the document is visible as i can see the id of document "001" but body is empty it says it is of BLOB type and is currently showing empty.

**3-** As the above point didn't worked for me i tried to search another viewer, and found [Couchbase Lite Viewer](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchbaseLiteViewer/releases/tag/v0.61)

but cannot use this one as its for MAC OS and i am using windows.

**4-** Lastly i tried to search more and found [couchbase-lite-android-viewer](https://github.com/pkjvit/couchbase-lite-android-viewer)

When trying to use the above one, on starting the viewer there is a crash and i am unable to solve this one

```
 Process: com.couchbase.todocblviewer, PID: 17575
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getPageSize()I in class Lcom/pkj/wow/paginationview/PaginationView; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.pkj.wow.paginationview.PaginationView' appears in /data/app/com.couchbase.todocblviewer-1/base.apk)
        at com.pkj.wow.cblite.viewer.ui.dbdetail.DatabaseDetailFragment.onSaveInstanceState(DatabaseDetailFragment.java:96)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:2526)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:2862)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:957)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.destroyItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:1039)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:3089)
        at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:284)
        at com.pkj.wow.cblite.viewer.ui.adapter.DatabasePagerAdapter.update(DatabasePagerAdapter.java:28)
        at com.pkj.wow.cblite.viewer.ui.console.ConsoleActivity.updateTableViewPager(ConsoleActivity.java:73)
        at com.pkj.wow.cblite.viewer.ui.console.ConsolePresenter$2.onDataLoaded(ConsolePresenter.java:59)
        at com.pkj.wow.cblite.viewer.data.AppDataManager$2$1.run(AppDataManager.java:142)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6617)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

I am unable to find any viewer for couchbase lite that supports Windows 10. I want to save documents are view the saved data during development.

Can somebody please help me out with this. It would be a great help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I too tried this approach and like you found the data saved as a blob. In the end I gave up and setup couchbase server with sync gateway replicating to it, then its simple to see this mirrored data in cb server on port 4984. Its not Sqlite compact toolbox but you can see the data.

Comment: Your SQLite viewer is correct.
CouchbaseLite stores blobs in files.  This is a necessary optimization because of the way that SQLite manages memory.  As with, e.g., git, the blob is content-addressable: its name on the file system is the hash of its content.  The files are stored in the application file-system sandbox, in the "files" directory, alongside the database.